# Physical size of MS SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How to find what the physical size of table in MS Sql 2005?
Is it possible using sql query or not?
Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try the stored procedure:

```
exec sp_spaceused TableName
```

For all tables you could use:

```
exec sp_Msforeachtable 'exec sp_spaceused ''?'''
```

Comment: forgot to remove table name there for a second ^^

Comment: For the all tables method above you can run into: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the built-in report (in 2008 at least).

Right-click the database in MS-SMS then select Reports > Standard Reports > Disk Usage by Table from the context menu.

The results are exportable to Excel.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [sp_spaceused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776(SQL.90).aspx) system procedure:

```
EXECUTE sp_spaceused 'YourTable'
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT table_schema,
table_name,
ROUND(data_length/1024/1024,2) total_size_mb
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'emp_master' AND table_schema = 'emp_database';

Comment: The query is not working. 'data_length' column cannot be found.